# ggplot2: control absolute plot size in R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to, but already love plotting with the `ggplot2` package. There is one issue I still do not know how to achieve: can I, somehow, set the absolute size of a plot in RStudio within a ggplot-command?
I know, that I can

- adjust the relative size of the x- and y-axes via `theme (aspect.ratio)`.
- set the final absolute size of a plot when exporting via `ggsave (width, height)`.

However, I'd wish to have a realistic preview of the plots I create within R-Studio, preferably in the plot-panel. Of course I could try and adjust the plot-panel size by eye - however, this is not very precise and not reproducable.

The only working solution that I know is to open a new device with definde size (for example via `x11 (width = 3, height = 3)`). However, I'd prefer ommiting to open a new window.

I can think of two options:

- programatically set the plot-panel size in R-Studio or
- set an absolute plot size which is only drawn if the plot-panel is
  large enough.

For both, I have to admit that I don't know how to. For me, an optimal solution could be called as an argument within `ggplot ()`.

Why is this important to me? --> a graph created in R-Studio might look quite nice, but when exported and shrinked to publication size, the text elements, axes and plot-content might look somewhat disproportional. Most of the time, the plots I create are bigger in R-Studio than my focal plot size.

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, I have no issue saving my plots. I ask for a realistic preview of my plots in RStudio. So that the plot I see in the plot-panel is exactly the same plot which is saved by ggsave. I'd like to tweak the plot in RStudio until I am satisfied with tho look while the size fits with the requirements, let's say of an scientific journal. This means: the plot in the plot-panel should be, for example, 90 mm x 90 mm in size. I hopw, this makes my question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you above, the size of the plot is dependent on the size of the window in RStudio or whatever you set it as if you are exporting it. However, if you want to keep a constant aspect ratio, you could try the following:

```
aspect_ratio <- 2.5
height <- 7
ggsave(g, height = 7, width = 7 * aspect_ratio
```

Link to documentation: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html

Comment: Perhaps my comment above is helpful: I know how to save my plots in the desired size and aspect ratio. However, I do not know how to define the absolute size of the plot in the plot-panel. If a journal requires plots of lets say 90 mm x 90 mm, it would be very nice to have a 90 mm x 90 mm plot in the plot panel to see how my final plot will look like.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question. The dev.new() function might provide you with the desired result. Have a look at the code below.

```
dev.new(width = 90, height = 90, unit = "mm")
plot(desired_graph)
```

Comment: (i) `dev.new ()` opens a new window for me, but the size specifications seem to be ignored (`x11 ()` is a working alternative with the slightly annoying drawback of only accepting inches [?]).
(ii) opening a new graph device is the "second best" option for me. I'd really prefer to keep working with the default graph panel integrated in the R Studio GUI.